# Pandas dataframe group: sum one column, take first element from others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'row':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'add': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'take1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'take2': ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77'], 'range': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]})


   add  range  row take1 take2
0    1    100    1     a    11
1    2    200    1     b    22
2    3    300    2     c    33
3    4    400    2     d    44
4    5    500    3     e    55
5    6    600    3     f    66
6    7    700    3     g    77
```

I want to group it by the `row` column, then add up entries in `add` column, but take the first entry from `take1` and `take2`, and select the min and max from range:

```
   add    row take1 take2  min_range   max_range
0    3      1     a    11    100        200
1    7      2     c    33    300        400
2    18     3     e    55    500        700
```

Comment: You're assuming the data is always sorted, or what defines "first entry"?

Comment: First entry by index within the group

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by dict, but then some cleaning is necessary, because get `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
#create a dictionary of column names and functions to apply to that column

d = {'add':'sum', 'take1':'first', 'take2':'first', 'range':['min','max']}

#group by the row column and apply the corresponding aggregation to each 
#column as specified in the dictionary d
df = x.groupby('row', as_index=False).agg(d)

#rename some columns
df = df.rename(columns={'first':'', 'sum':''})
df.columns = ['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(x).strip('_') for x in df.columns] 
print (df)
   row take1  range_min  range_max take2  add
0    1     a        100        200    11    3
1    2     c        300        400    33    7
2    3     e        500        700    55   18
```

Details : Aggregate the columns based by the functions specified in the dictionary :

```
df = x.groupby('row', as_index=False).agg(d)
```

```
row range      take2 take1 add
        min  max first first sum
0   1   100  200    11     a   3
1   2   300  400    33     c   7
2   3   500  700    55     e  18
```

Replacing column names `sum` and `first` with `''` will lead to

```
 row range      take2 take1 add
        min  max                
0   1   100  200    11     a   3
1   2   300  400    33     c   7
2   3   500  700    55     e  18
```

List comprehension on columns by using string formatters will get the desired column names. Assigning it to `df.columns` will get the desired output.

Comment: Please see my comment above, let me know if your solution is compliant

Comment: Also getting this error
In [58]: df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('_')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-a70f808b80f4> in <module>()
----> 1 df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('_')

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str

Comment: I think yes, if think `first` function always return first value. Not necessary sorting.

Comment: Ok, I add another solution for it.

Comment: Can you please explain your solution a little bit? What each line does, what it produces? For example, I am confused why after the first line df=x.goupby... the resulting dataframe has 2 rows of row names, it looks weird. That way I won't have to ask similar questions again :)

Comment: I am on phone only, but I try. If use dictionary as argument in `agg` function it aggregate all columns define in keys of dict with values of dict which can be string or list of functions. If have at least one list get multiindex - 2 rows header. So last is necessary flattening, e.g. by list comprehension.

Comment: @jezrael what if I have many columns that I cannot write down all eg. I want to do 'add':'sum', 'range':['min','max'], 600 more columns: 'first'. Do you have a practical solution for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had, without column renaming/sorting.

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'row':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'add': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'take1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'take2': ['11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77'], 'range': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]})
x.reset_index(inplace = True)
min_cols = x.ix[x.groupby(['row'])['index'].idxmin().values][['row','take1','take2']]
x_grouped = x.groupby(['row']).agg({'add':'sum','range':[np.min, np.max]})

x_out = pd.merge(x_grouped,min_cols, how = 'left',left_index = True, right_on = ['row'])

print x_out


   (add, sum)  (range, amin)  (range, amax)  row take1 take2
0           3            100            200    1     a    11
2           7            300            400    2     c    33
4          18            500            700    3     e    55
```